# How do I avoid getting a file marked "changed" after modifying it in a before-clientcheckin trigger?

Tags: plasticscm

I have written a before-clientcheckin script to write the predicted changeset number into certain files on a user check-in operation. The script appears to be running successfully in that the new changeset number is being written to the target files and the check-in operation completes successfully.

BUT... unfortunately on check in completion a "Changed" copy of the file still shows up in the Pending Changes window. Bizarrely, this "changed" version of the file is identical to the one that was just checked in. I can get rid of it by undoing the change, which then makes my workspace and the repository equal again, with the correctly-versioned file still intact.

It seems that although the check-in is succeeding, the modification of the file by the script *after* the user commences the check-in operation is marking the file as changed again - even though its contents are actually unchanged.

Does anyone know how to avoid this scenario? There's no mention of this kind of issue in the Plastic Trigger manual, and although I have seen other posts from people trying to do something similar in a before-clientcheckin script, no one seems to have encountered this particular problem.

My Plastic version is 7.0.16.2421, running on Windows 10.

Any help would be much appreciated!